# Subsequent httpClient calls return initial calls results

Tags: java, androidhttpclient

I have these methods in a class called HttpHelper.  Now the initial call validates user credentials and returns true.  That is expected.  The next call is to register a user.  That seems to go fine with no hiccups and is to return the new user ID.  Instead of returning the user ID it returns true again.  Almost like it is cached and just returning the result from the initial call.   Anyone have any thoughts as to why this might occur?

```
private static CookieStore sCookieStore;

private static String invoke(HttpUriRequest request)
            throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        String result = null;
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // restore cookie
        if (sCookieStore != null) {
            httpClient.setCookieStore((org.apache.http.client.CookieStore) sCookieStore);
        }

        //request.addHeader("Host", "localhost");
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent()));
        for (String s = reader.readLine(); s != null; s = reader.readLine()) {
            builder.append(s);
        }
        result = builder.toString();
        Log.d(TAG, "result is ( " + result + " )");

        // store cookie
        sCookieStore = (CookieStore) ((AbstractHttpClient) httpClient).getCookieStore();
        return result;
    }

public static String invokeGet(String action, List<NameValuePair> params) {
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(API_URL);
            sb.append(action);
            if (params != null) {
                for (NameValuePair param : params) {
                    sb.append("?");
                    sb.append(param.getName());
                    sb.append("=");
                    sb.append(param.getValue());
                }
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "url is" + sb.toString());
            //HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URLEncoder.encode(sb.toString(), "UTF-8"));
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(sb.toString());

            return invoke(httpGet);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static String invokeGet(String action) {
        return invokeGet(action, null);
    }
```

Here are the calls I am making.   As specified above the authResult variable would result in a string result of true.  The nextResult should hold the user ID value but instead holds the value true like from the initial request:

```
String authResult = HttpHelper.invokeGet("<url to validate user>");

        if (this.URL.indexOf("register") > -1)      
            String nextResult = HttpHelper.invokeGet(this.URL);
        else
            String nextResult = HttpHelper.invokeGet(this.URL);
```

**UPDATED**:  added in the `sCookieStore` variable.

**UPDATED 2**:  adding in the methods that are being called via the API (MVC .NET):

`authResult` variable would get this result:

```
public bool Get(String userName, String userPassword)
        {
            Task<IdentityUser> iu = _repo.FindUser(userName, userPassword);

            if (iu != null)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, false);
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

`nextResult` variable should get this result:

```
[HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> RegisterUser(String userName, String userPassword, String huh)
    {
        UserModel userModel = new UserModel();
        userModel.ConfirmPassword = userPassword;
        userModel.UserName = userName;
        userModel.Password = userPassword;

        String userID = "";

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        IdentityResult result = await _repo.RegisterUser(userModel);

        IHttpActionResult errorResult = GetErrorResult(result);

        if (errorResult != null)
        {
            return errorResult;
        }
        else
        {
            Task<IdentityUser> iu = _repo.FindUser(userModel.UserName, userModel.Password);

            using (var context = new AuthContext())
            {
                var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>(context);
                var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);

                userID = iu.Result.Id;

                result = await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(userID, "Users");

                errorResult = GetErrorResult(result);

                if (errorResult != null)
                {
                    return errorResult;
                }
            }
        }

        return Ok("userID:" + userID);
    }
```

Comment: I assume you are hitting the correct URLs and have tested their reply using curl, right?

Also, please note you have a bug at `for (NameValuePair param : params) { sb.append("?");..` (you're skipping that branch right now but it will hit you later).

Comment: @Vlad - The API I am using is written in .NET MVC.  I tested it through Visual Studio 2013 and everything ran fine in there.  The NameValuePair I just included because, as of right now, I haven't even used that portion of the method with passing in the parameters.  So I haven't even debugged that portion of that code yet.  Only added because of the other invokeGet and passing null which I am currently using.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like *authResult* is going to fire *invokeGet* 2 times, giving it the same argument (*this.URL*). Within *invokeGet*, the variable *sb* is going to be *this.URL* both times the function fires.

This is a bit curious to me:

```
   // restore cookie
    if (sCookieStore != null) {
        httpClient.setCookieStore((org.apache.http.client.CookieStore) sCookieStore);
    }
```

then at the end,

```
// store cookie
    sCookieStore = (CookieStore) ((AbstractHttpClient) httpClient).getCookieStore();
```

When is sCookieStore defined? It could be that the cookies aren't being handled correctly and you're making two fresh connections. If getting and setting the cookies is the issue, it might be better to get a cookie if it exists at the beginning of *invoke*, then set the new one at the end.

Comment: authResult isn't going to fire invokeGet 2 times.  The initial call is to validate the user.  Then based on the URL, if it contains the word register, it then does its thing.  This will later be changed to an invokePost but was only done for testing purposes to get the code working and so I could test through the browser as well.  sCookieStore is a static variable for that static class.   I need to pass that cookie along to each request because the initial user validation sets that variable and then will get used for authorization for subsequent requests via the API.

Comment: Also I checked via the debugger in android and within the invoke method, for the request variable, it does show the correct URL being used for each instance.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was unclear with what I'd meant -- it sounded like from your description you were firing authResult multiple times. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes and No.  I am firing authResult once and then firing another URL.  The problem is the result comes back with the same result as the authResult did when it should come back with a user ID.  During debugging the request variable did hold the appropriate URLs for each request.  So I am not firing it twice from what the code is showing but the result is coming back like authResult was fired twice.  Make sense?

Comment: It'd be helpful to include in your description everything going on, as that's kinda different than what's described :-). To me, at least. It still sounds like invoke isn't making its request in the context of the existing session. I'd look at what you're getting in your get/set methods, and when, for those cookies to make sure they're not causing the issue.

Comment: It is described the same way just with different wording up top as I mentioned the nextResult holding the value of authResult when it should hold user ID.  Everything from the debugger is showing that each request has the appropriate URL values for each before hitting the execute command.  It's what returns is getting all jumbled up.  So the httpClient, at least within the variables themselves, have all the correct information.  From the point it sends and returns is where the mixup is happening.  At least, from what I am seeing from my debugging.

Comment: I completely removed the setting of the cookie just to make sure that wasn't causing any hiccups and the same result happened again.  So it is not the cookie association on the httpClient that is causing the mixup.